# How can We create dynamic route navigation Link in angular with multi level children and which will recreate whole navigation on reload

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I wanted to create a navigation list based on some configuration.
like an Array of

```
export interface LeftNavModel {
name: string,
route: string,
iconName?: string,
data?: any }
```

so navigation data will look something like

```
[
  {
    name: "First Route",
    route:"first",
    sectionName: "First Section",
    iconName: "home",
    children: [
      {
        name: "First Child Route",
        route:`first/firstChild`,
        iconName: "folder"
        children: [
          {
            name: "First Sub Child Route",
            route:"first/firstChild/firstSubChild",
            iconName: "image"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This data will create nav link like
[image]

And in a component create routerLink using the routes from the config JSON.
I was able to create the same and is working fine. The issue is I wanted to share the navigated URL so other users can open the same page with navigation created dynamically.

Page Refresh can be handled by keeping config as state in router. Or using any storage mechanism like localStorage. But how can we share the link along with config data.
Passing config as queryParam will create huge url. Any other option for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a solution for this issue, as there are no other answers available. I will now share what I have implemented to fulfill the requirement.

I have created a config with all the required navigation for my application. Navigation component is loaded with required section of the config when a particular view is loaded

Config Sample

```
export const navConfig = [{
sectionName:"Search",
i18nKey: "search",
sectionTopDivider: true,
menuList:[
  {
    menuName: "Company1",
    i18nKey: "company1",
    route: "app/company1",
    prependIconName: "search",
    customClass:"text-success",
    appendIconName: "image",
  },
  {
    menuName: "Company2",
    i18nKey: "company2",
    route: "app/company2",
    prependIconName: "search",
    appendIconName: "image"
  }
]},{
sectionName:"OverView",
i18nKey:"OverView",
sectionTopDivider: true,
menuList:[
  {
    menuName: "Company 1 Overview",
    i18nKey: "company1 overview",
    route: "app/company1-overview",
    prependIconName: "home",
    appendIconName: "image",
    menuList: [
      {
        menuName: "Company1 Child Route",
        i18nKey: "",
        route: "company1/[departmentId]",
        prependIconName: "",
        appendSVGIconName: "",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Company 2 Overview",
    i18nKey: "company2 overview",
    route: "app/company2-overview",
    prependIconName: "home",
    appendIconName: "image",
    menuList: [
      {
        menuName: "Company2 Child Route",
        i18nKey: "",
        route: "company2/[departmentId]",
        prependIconName: "",
        appendSVGIconName: "",
      }
    ]
  }
]}]
```

All the application related files are attached to the snippet.
You can insert this navigation component to your applicationlike below

```
<app-left-navbar></app-left-navbar>
```

To load the navigation config, inject navigation service into your constructor and load required navigation config
Eg:

```
private navService: LeftNavbarService, 
this.navService.setNavConfigList(navConfig);
```

Where navConfig is your required nav config as per the model left-nav.model.ts

If you wanted to load a particular section from the config, you can do it like below

```
this.route.url.subscribe(url=>{
  let headerModel: HeaderModel = {
    mainLabel: "New Header",
    mainIconName: "menu",
    subLabel: "Back to dashboard",
    subIconName: "arrow_back",
    subRoute: "./"
  }
  this.navService.setNavHeader(headerModel);  // new header model if required

  let defaultNavConfig = this.navService.getNavConfigList(); // featch loaded config from nav service
  let section = this.navService.getConfig(defaultNavConfig, 'sectionName', 'OverView'); //fetch required section from config using section name
  section.hidden = false; //edit section visibility if required

  this.navService.setNavList(defaultNavConfig); // set nav with updated config. You can edit already existing config or can add new config if required
})
```

Please go through the service to understand the working.

```js
//left-navbar.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, take } from 'rxjs';
import { HeaderModel, LeftMenuConfig, MenuItemConfig } from '../models/left-nav.model';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LeftNavbarService {

  navConfigList!: LeftMenuConfig[];//new BehaviorSubject<LeftMenuConfig[]>([]);
  navList = new BehaviorSubject<LeftMenuConfig[]>([]);
  headerModel = new BehaviorSubject<HeaderModel>(<HeaderModel>{});
  // footerModel = new BehaviorSubject<HeaderModel>(<HeaderModel>{});
  activeNavModel!: MenuItemConfig;
  constructor() { }

  getNavList(): Observable<LeftMenuConfig[]> {
    return this.navList.asObservable();
  }

  getNavConfigList(): LeftMenuConfig[] {
    return _.cloneDeep(this.navConfigList);
  }

  setNavList(navList: LeftMenuConfig[]) {
    this.navList.next(navList)
  }

  setNavConfigList(navList: LeftMenuConfig[]) {
    this.navConfigList = navList;
  }

  getNavHeader(): Observable<HeaderModel> {
    return this.headerModel.asObservable();
  }

  setNavHeader(headerModel: HeaderModel) {
    this.headerModel.next(headerModel);
  }

  // getNavFooter(): Observable<HeaderModel> {
  //   return this.footerModel.asObservable();
  // }

  // setNavFooter(footerModel: HeaderModel) {
  //   this.footerModel.next(footerModel);
  // }

  getNavListPromise() {
    return this.navList.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  }

  setActiveNavModel(navModel: MenuItemConfig) {
    this.activeNavModel = navModel;
  }

  getActiveNavModel() {
    return this.activeNavModel;
  }

  getConfig(listToMatch: Array<any>, key: string, value: string): any {
    let matched;
    for (let i = 0; i < listToMatch.length; i++) {
      let item = listToMatch[i];
      if (item[key] === value) {
        matched = item;
        break;
      }
      if (item.menuList && item.menuList.length) {
        matched = this.getConfig(item.menuList, 'menuName', value);
        if (matched) break;
      }
    }
    return matched;
  }
}

//left-nav.model.ts

export interface LeftMenuConfig {
    sectionName: string,
    i18nKey: string,
    sectionTopDivider?: boolean,
    sectionBottomDivider?: boolean,
    hidden?:boolean,
    menuList: MenuItemConfig[]
}

export interface MenuItemConfig {
    menuName: string,
    i18nKey: string,
    route: string,
    prependIconName?: ((item: MenuItemConfig) => string) | string,
    prependSVGIconName?: ((item: MenuItemConfig) => string) | string,
    appendIconName?: ((item: MenuItemConfig) => string) | string,
    appendSVGIconName?: ((item: MenuItemConfig) => string) | string,
    data?: any,
    rawHtml?: ((item: MenuItemConfig) => string) | string,
    customClass?: ((item: MenuItemConfig) => string) | string, 
    formatterComponent?: any,
    hidden?: boolean,
    disabled?:boolean,
    privilege?:string,
    selected?: boolean,
    menuList?: MenuItemConfig[]
}

export interface HeaderModel {
    mainLabel: string,
    mainRoute?: string,
    mainIconName?: string,
    mainSvgIconName?: string,
    subLabel?: string,
    subRoute?: string,
    subIconName?: string,
    subSvgIconName?: string,
}

//left-navbar.component.ts

import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HeaderModel, LeftMenuConfig, MenuItemConfig } from '../models/left-nav.model';
import { LeftNavbarService } from '../services/left-navbar.service';
import { animateText, onSideNavChange } from './left-nav-animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-left-navbar',
  templateUrl: './left-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-navbar.component.scss'],
  animations: [onSideNavChange, animateText]
})
export class LeftNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private navbarService: LeftNavbarService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
      )
      .subscribe(
        (event) => {
          let url = this.route.url;
          console.log(url);
        }
      );

  }

  navList!: Observable<LeftMenuConfig[]>;
  headerModel!: Observable<HeaderModel>;
  footerModel!: any;
  expanded = true;
  navState = true;
  @Input() leftPadding: number = 0; // Initial left padding of list item
  @Input() listNodePadding: number = 20 // Left padding of children list items for each level

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navList = this.navbarService.getNavList();
    this.headerModel = this.navbarService.getNavHeader();
    this.footerModel = {
      mainLabel: 'Help & Support',
      mainRoute: '',
      mainIconName: 'help_outline',
      subLabel: 'Help Sub Label',
      subRoute: '',
      subIconName: 'copyright',
    };
  }

  getCustomIcon(item: any, key: string) {
    if (item[key] && typeof (item[key]) === 'function') {
      return item[key](item);
    } else return item[key];
  }

  toggleLeftNav() {
    this.navState = !this.navState;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.expanded = this.navState;
    }, 200)
  }

  onActivateRoute(isActive: boolean, item: MenuItemConfig) {
    if (isActive) {
      this.navbarService.setActiveNavModel(item);
    };
  }
}
```

```css
//left-navbar.component.scss

.left-nav-container {
    ::ng-deep {
        .mat-list-item {
            height: 40px !important;
            align-items: center;

            // border-left: 4px solid transparent;
            // &.active {
            //     // border-left: 4px solid #303030;
            // }
            .mat-list-item-content {
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 0 0 0 4px !important;
                width: 100%;
            }

            &:disabled {
                cursor: not-allowed;
                pointer-events: none;
                opacity: 0.6;
            }
        }

        .mat-subheader {
            padding: 0 !important;
        }

        .mat-nav-list.footer-section {
            margin-top: auto !important;
        }

        .mat-list-text {
            padding-left: 0 !important;
        }
    }

    &.expanded {
        // min-width: 220px;
    }

    &.collapsed {
        ::ng-deep {
            .mat-list-item {
                // width: 40px !important;
                justify-content: center;
            }
        }
    }

    .menu-group-container {
        padding: 0 4px;

        &.active-container {
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #e8ecef80;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    }

    .active-container {
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #e8ecef80;
        padding: 4px;
    }

}

.expandCollapseBtn {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #8b9daf;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    right: -12px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 4;
    cursor: pointer;

    span.material-icons {
        color: white;
    }
}

.child-indicator-elm {
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;

    &::before {
        content: "";
        float: left;
        width: 8px;
        height: inherit;
        background: transparent;
        border: 2px solid #A3B1BF;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        border-top: 0;
        border-right: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }

    &::after {
        content: "";
        float: right;
        width: 4px;
        height: 4px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        right: -3px;
        bottom: -1px;
        background-color: #A3B1BF;
    }

}

.display-none {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
//left-navbar.component.html
<div [@onSideNavChange]="navState ? 'open' : 'close'" class="left-nav-container p-2 h-100 position-relative"
    [ngClass]="{'expanded':expanded, 'collapsed':!expanded}">
    <span class="expandCollapseBtn position-absolute" (click)="toggleLeftNav()">
        <span *ngIf="expanded" class="material-icons">arrow_left</span>
        <span *ngIf="!expanded" class="material-icons">arrow_right</span>
    </span>
    <div class="w-100 h-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-stretched justify-content-start">
        <ng-container *ngIf="headerModel | async">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="headerTmpl; context:{item: headerModel | async, class: 'header-section'}">
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-nav-list dense>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of navList | async">
                <ng-container *ngIf="!item?.hidden">
                    <mat-divider *ngIf="item?.sectionTopDivider"></mat-divider>
                    <span *ngIf="item?.sectionName && expanded" mat-subheader>{{item?.sectionName}}</span>
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let menuItem of item?.menuList">
                        <div [appUserPrivilege]="menuItem?.privilege" class="menu-group-container"
                            [ngClass]="{'p-0':!expanded, 'active-container': menuItem?.selected}">
                            <ng-container *ngIf="menuItem?.formatterComponent">
                                <app-formatter-navlink [navModel]="menuItem"></app-formatter-navlink>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container *ngIf="menuItem?.rawHtml">
                                <a mat-list-item class="d-flex rounded" [routerLink]="menuItem?.route"
                                    routerLinkActive="active"
                                    [innerHTML]="menuItem | navCustomHandler : 'rawHtml' | safeHtml">
                                </a>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container
                                *ngIf="!menuItem?.formatterComponent && !menuItem?.rawHtml && !menuItem?.hidden">
                                <div appCustomClassHandler [menuItem]="menuItem">
                                    <a [disabled]="menuItem?.disabled" mat-list-item
                                        (isActiveChange)="onActivateRoute($event,menuItem)"
                                        [routerLink]="menuItem?.route" class="d-flex rounded"
                                        [style.padding-left.px]="expanded ? leftPadding: 0"
                                        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" [state]="{config: menuItem}"
                                        routerLinkActive="active">
                                        <mat-icon *ngIf="menuItem?.prependIconName" matListIcon
                                            [innerText]="menuItem | navCustomHandler: 'prependIconName'"></mat-icon>
                                        <mat-icon *ngIf="menuItem?.prependSVGIconName" mat-list-icon
                                            svgIcon="{{ getCustomIcon(menuItem, 'prependSVGIconName') }}"></mat-icon>
                                        <div class="ps-1" [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'" matLine>
                                            {{menuItem?.i18nKey}}
                                        </div>
                                        <mat-icon *ngIf="menuItem?.appendIconName"
                                            [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'"
                                            [innerText]="menuItem | navCustomHandler: 'appendIconName'"></mat-icon>
                                        <mat-icon class="d-flex" *ngIf="menuItem?.appendSVGIconName"
                                            [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'"
                                            svgIcon="{{ getCustomIcon(menuItem, 'appendSVGIconName') }}"></mat-icon>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container *ngIf="!menuItem.hidden && menuItem?.menuList">
                                <ng-container
                                    *ngTemplateOutlet="navTmpl; context:{menuItem: menuItem, leftPadding: leftPadding + listNodePadding }">
                                </ng-container>
                            </ng-container>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                    <mat-divider *ngIf="item?.sectionBottomDivider"></mat-divider>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-nav-list>
        <ng-container *ngIf="footerModel">
            <ng-container
                *ngTemplateOutlet="footerTmpl; context:{item: footerModel, class: 'footer-section', footer: true}">
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #navTmpl let-parentConfig="menuItem" let-menuItem="menuItem" let-leftPadding="leftPadding">
    <mat-nav-list dense>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItem?.menuList; let i=index;">
            <ng-container *ngIf="menuItem && !menuItem?.hidden">
                <div [ngClass]="{'active-container':menuItem?.selected}" [appUserPrivilege]="menuItem?.privilege">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="menuItem?.formatterComponent">
                        <app-formatter-navlink [navModel]="menuItem"></app-formatter-navlink>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="menuItem?.rawHtml">
                        <a mat-list-item class="d-flex rounded" [routerLink]="menuItem?.route" routerLinkActive="active"
                            [innerHTML]="menuItem.rawHtml(menuItem) | safeHtml">
                        </a>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="!menuItem?.formatterComponent && !menuItem?.rawHtml">
                        <div class="position-relative" appCustomClassHandler [menuItem]="menuItem">
                            <span *ngIf="expanded" appFluidHeight [refElement]="linkRef" [parentConfig]="parentConfig"
                                [index]="i" [style.bottom.px]="linkRef['_element']?.nativeElement?.offsetHeight/2"
                                [style.left.px]="leftPadding" class="child-indicator-elm"></span>
                            <a #linkRef [disabled]="menuItem?.disabled" mat-list-item
                                [style.padding-left.px]="expanded ? leftPadding: 0" class="d-flex rounded"
                                (isActiveChange)="onActivateRoute($event,menuItem)" [routerLink]="menuItem?.route"
                                [state]="{config: menuItem}" routerLinkActive="active"
                                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                                <mat-icon *ngIf="menuItem?.prependIconName" matListIcon
                                    [innerText]="menuItem | navCustomHandler: 'prependIconName'"></mat-icon>
                                <mat-icon *ngIf="menuItem?.prependSVGIconName" mat-list-icon
                                    svgIcon="{{ getCustomIcon(menuItem, 'prependSVGIconName') }}"></mat-icon>
                                <div class="ps-1" [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'" matLine>
                                    {{menuItem?.i18nKey}}
                                </div>
                                <mat-icon *ngIf="menuItem?.appendIconName" [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'"
                                    [innerText]="menuItem | navCustomHandler: 'appendIconName'"></mat-icon>
                                <mat-icon class="d-flex" *ngIf="menuItem?.appendSVGIconName"
                                    [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'"
                                    svgIcon="{{ getCustomIcon(menuItem, 'appendSVGIconName') }}"></mat-icon>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="menuItem?.menuList">
                        <ng-container
                            *ngTemplateOutlet="navTmpl; context:{menuItem: menuItem, leftPadding: leftPadding + listNodePadding}">
                        </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-nav-list>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #headerTmpl let-item="item" let-class="class" let-isFooter="footer">
    <mat-nav-list [ngClass]="class" dense>
        <mat-divider *ngIf="isFooter"></mat-divider>
        <ng-container *ngIf="item?.mainLabel">
            <a mat-list-item [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'" [ngClass]="{'d-flex mainLabel rounded': true}"
                [routerLink]="item?.mainRoute" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="item.mainIconName" matListIcon>{{item?.mainIconName}}</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="item.mainSvgIcon" mat-list-icon svgIcon="{{ item.mainSvgIcon }}"></mat-icon>
                <div [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'" matLine class="ms-2 ml-2">{{item?.mainLabel}}</div>
            </a>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="item?.subLabel">
            <a mat-list-item [ngClass]="{'d-flex subLabel rounded': true}" [routerLink]="item?.subRoute"
                routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="item.subIconName" matListIcon>{{item?.subIconName}}</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="item.subSvgIcon" mat-list-icon svgIcon="{{ item.subSvgIcon }}"></mat-icon>
                <div [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'" matLine class="ms-2 ml-2">{{item?.subLabel}}</div>
            </a>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-nav-list>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #footerTmpl let-item="item" let-class="class">
    <mat-nav-list [ngClass]="class" dense>
        <mat-divider *ngIf="class"></mat-divider>
        <ng-container *ngIf="item?.mainLabel">
            <a mat-list-item [ngClass]="{'d-flex mainLabel rounded': true}" [routerLink]="item?.mainRoute"
                routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="item.mainIconName" matListIcon>{{item?.mainIconName}}</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="item.mainSvgIcon" mat-list-icon svgIcon="{{ item.mainSvgIcon }}"></mat-icon>
                <div [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'" matLine class="ms-2 ml-2">{{item?.mainLabel}}</div>
            </a>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="item?.subLabel">
            <a mat-list-item [ngClass]="{'d-flex subLabel rounded': true}" [routerLink]="item?.subRoute"
                routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="item.subIconName" matListIcon>{{item?.subIconName}}</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="item.subSvgIcon" mat-list-icon svgIcon="{{ item.subSvgIcon }}"></mat-icon>
                <div [@animateText]="expanded ? 'show' : 'hide'" matLine class="ms-2 ml-2">{{item?.subLabel}}</div>
            </a>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-nav-list>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in a project I am working on a while back.

I am using bootstrap accordions for my sidebar, and as such needed to give each menu item an id. You could accomplish the same thing with anything though doesn't have to be bootstrap.

**Create a class to represent the menu/nav items (Mine is something like this)**

```
export class MenuItem {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  icon: string;
  url?: string;
  children?: MenuItem[];
}
```

**Create a menu items array which will store the list of items. This is a shortened version of what mine looks like:**

```
export const menuItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'dashboard',
    url: 'dashboard',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Organizational Documents',
    icon: 'library_books',
    children: [
      {
        id: 3,
        text: 'View',
        icon: 'search',
        url: 'organizational-documents/view',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: 'Qualifications',
    icon: 'school',
    children: [
      {
        id: 5,
        text: 'Create',
        icon: 'create',
        url: 'qualifications/create',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        text: 'View',
        icon: 'search',
        url: 'qualifications/view',
      },
    ],
  },
 {
    id: 7,
    text: 'Programmes',
    icon: 'library_books',
    children: [
      {
        id: 8,
        text: 'Create',
        icon: 'create',
        children: [
          {
            id: 9,
            text: 'Learnership',
            icon: 'add',
            url: 'programmes/create/learnership',
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            text: 'Internship',
            icon: 'add',
            url: 'programmes/create/internship',
          },
        ],
      },
{
        id: 11,
        text: 'View',
        icon: 'search',
        children: [
          {
            id: 12,
            text: 'Learnerships',
            icon: 'search',
            url: 'programmes/view/learnerships',
          },
          {
            id: 13,
            text: 'Internships',
            icon: 'search',
            url: 'programmes/view/internships',
          },
        ],
      },
]
```

**Initialize the menu items from the component that contains the nav items**

```
import { menuItems } from '../menuItems';

public ngOnInit() {
    this.renderMenu();
}

private renderMenu(): void {
  this.renderedMenuItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(menuItems));
}
```

**Add HTML similar to below in order to iterate over the menu items**

```
 <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-open overflow-auto shadow">
    <div class="accordion accordion-flush mb-2" id="sidebarAccordion">
      <div *ngFor="let item of renderedMenuItems">
        <div *ngIf="!item.children">
          <a
            id="flush-{{ item.id }}"
            class="
              fs-6
              d-flex
              align-items-center
              p-2
              pt-3
              pb-3
              cursor-pointer
              non-dropdown
            "
            routerLink="{{ item.url }}"
            routerLinkActive="active-route-dash"
          >
            <mat-icon class="ms-1 me-3">{{ item.icon }}</mat-icon>
            {{ item.text }}
          </a>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="item.children" class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header m-0" id="flush-{{ item.id }}">
            <div
              id="menu-button-{{ item.id }}"
              class="accordion-button collapsed cursor-pointer p-2"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              attr.data-bs-target="#flush-collapse-{{ item.id }}"
              aria-expanded="false"
              attr.aria-controls="flush-collapse-{{ item.id }}"
            >
              <mat-icon class="ms-1 me-3">{{ item.icon }}</mat-icon>
              {{ item.text }}
            </div>
          </h2>
          <div
            id="flush-collapse-{{ item.id }}"
            class="accordion-collapse collapse"
            attr.aria-labelledby="flush-{{ item.id }}"
            data-bs-parent="#sidebarAccordion"
          >
            <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
              <li *ngFor="let child of item.children">
                <div
                  *ngIf="child.children"
                  class="accordion accordion-flush"
                  id="accordion-{{ child.id }}"
                >
                  <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header m-0" id="flush-{{ child.id }}">
                      <div
                        id="menu-button-{{ child.id }}"
                        class="accordion-button collapsed cursor-pointer p-2"
                        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        attr.data-bs-target="#flush-collapse-{{ child.id }}"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                        attr.aria-controls="flush-collapse-{{ child.id }}"
                      >
                        <div class="ps-2 fw-normal d-flex align-items-center">
                          <mat-icon class="ms-1 me-3">{{
                            child.icon
                          }}</mat-icon>
                          {{ child.text }}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </h2>
                    <div
                      id="flush-collapse-{{ child.id }}"
                      class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                      attr.aria-labelledby="flush-{{ child.id }}"
                      attr.data-bs-parent="#accordion-{{ child.id }}"
                    >
                      <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                        <li *ngFor="let subChild of child.children">
                          <a
                            class="
                              cursor-pointer
                              nav-item
                              ps-4
                              d-flex
                              align-items-center
                              non-dropdown
                            "
                            routerLink="{{ subChild.url }}"
                            routerLinkActive="active-route-3rd"
                          >
                            <mat-icon class="ms-1 me-3">{{
                              subChild.icon
                            }}</mat-icon>
                            {{ subChild.text }}
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="!child.children">
                  <a
                    class="
                      cursor-pointer
                      nav-item
                      ps-3
                      d-flex
                      align-items-center
                      non-dropdown
                    "
                    routerLink="{{ child.url }}"
                    routerLinkActive="active-route-2nd"
                  >
                    <mat-icon class="ms-1 me-3">{{ child.icon }}</mat-icon>
                    {{ child.text }}
                  </a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

**With the above code, I end up with the following (after styling obviously)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in your case navigation config is already available. So it will be easy to create navigation based o that already existing config. In my case I dnt have the navigation config but created dynamically each time a navigation happens. So the issue is if I reload I dnt have that configuration using which I can recreate the left navigation. Also if I used local storage or state to store the config, I can able to open the page and reload existing config but shared URL will not be able to load navigation.